# How can I force zsh to write automatically complete path to history?

Tags: zsh, command-history, options

Suppose I did some time ago `cd /path/to/foo/bar` and then `evince file.pdf`. Now if I want to open `file.pdf` again I have also to do both steps again (using history). However I would do it in a single step. I.e. I want that *not* `evince file.pdf` is written to `.zsh_history` but `evince /path/to/foo/bar/file.pdf`. How can I achieve this for example by modifying my `.zshrc`? `evince` is only an example. It should work with any command.

Should I have any drawbacks in mind with this new behavior?

N.B: Currently I am using [`z`](https://github.com/agkozak/zsh-z) vor `cd` history and [`fzf`](https://github.com/unixorn/fzf-zsh-plugin) for general history.

Comment: What if you write `echo test $var` or `echo test.txt $(echo ..)` from within /bin? Should it change it to `/bin/echo /bin/test /bin/$var` (what if `$var` contains an absolute path), `/bin/echo /bin/test.txt /` (what if `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, should that be `/usr` instead for `..`)?

Comment: Good point. If possible variables maybe could ignored. Symlinks should be expanded.

Comment: In `ls -l --time-style long-iso ls`, `make CFLAGS=-g file.c install`, `man zsh`, `rsync foo bar:baz`, `env ls`..., how is zsh to know which of the arguments are relative paths to files that should be made absolute? That would require knowing (and parsing the same way they do) the full syntax of all the commands available on the system. If you think about it just a few minutes, you'll see it's not realistic.

Comment: What's about specifying a closed list of commands (e.g. "evince, okular,...") for which zsh should save the complete path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not something that could be done for arbitrary shell code as zsh has no way to know which of the words in the code are actually arguments that a command would treat as a file path let alone as a path relative to the current working directory at the time the code is stored onto the history.

For the simplest shell code such as `cmd with its literal arguments` and for a limited predefined set of commands, you could do something like:

```
commands_with_expanded_paths=(evince okular)
zshaddhistory() {
  local words=( ${(z)1%$'\n'} )
  if (( $commands_with_expanded_paths[(Ie)$words[1]] )); then
    local replaced_words=($words[1]) word
    for word in $words[2,-1]; do
      local decoded_word=${(Q)word}
      if [[ $decoded_word = [^/]* && -e $decoded_word ]]; then
        word=${(q+)decoded_word:P}
      fi
      replaced_words+=($word)
    done
    print -rs -- $replaced_words
    fc -p
  fi
}
```

Where if the first word is the name of a command in a given list, the remaining arguments are replaced with their absolute path if they're found to be relative paths to existing files in the text saved onto the history.